# Python - Get specific characters from text file or from list

Tags: python, string, list, file, text

I have a text file with this in it

> Curtain Open time: 8:00

When I wrote to the file I used this

```
File.write("Curtain Open Time: " + Var_CurtainOpenTime, + "\n")
```

I used the "\n" to go onto the next line for more data to be wrote. "Var_CurtainOpenTime" is a variable in this case it was "8:00". I have some code to read the line which looks like this:

```
FileRead = open('File.txt', 'r')
```

Printing this would read "Curtain Open Time: 8:00".

I want to be able to just get "8:00". I had previously used `FileRead.split(" ")` to separate each word but after the 8:00 I get `["Curtain", "Open", "Time:", "8:00\n"]`. So I believe I would need to remove the first 3 indexes somehow and somehow remove '\n' from the last index. I don't know how I would approach this. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, I will comment the explain

```
with open('File.txt') as f:
    [line.replace('\n','').split()[3:][0] for line in f][0]
```

or just:

```
FileRead = open('File.txt', 'r')

result = [line.replace('\n','').split()[3:][0] for line in FileRead][0]
```

Comment: You copy my answer with the missing point in the `split` part ;) I fix mine. fix yours

Comment: @efirvida aaaaaaah, you got me, yes I saw it was a god idea, but still not working fine, you also take a look at your answer :), you are too close

Answer (score 2):

**you just need to change from the .split(" ") to .split() and then get the last list item**

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
     print f.read().split()[-1]
```

Comment: careful ,the op wants the 3thd element! anyway is a plus one for the lead

Comment: I have tried this and In combination with FileRead = (FileRead[3::]) to remove the "Curtain Open Time". It removes the '\n' but once printed the ['8:00'] brackets and quotations still remain.

Comment: hahah @DamianLattenero thank u too, I just focus my answer on removing the `\n`, and forget the second part. But I just learned something new ... it was not necessary `.replace ('\n')` just using `.split()` without parameters, instead of `.split(" ")` did the trick so i update my answer

Comment: It returns 0 rather than 8:00

Comment: @ThePGT I update the code again, I forget to read the file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well once you have the list from the split, you can remove the first 3 terms by doing `l=l[3:]` (where l is your list). Then you can remove the `\n` by doing `s = s[:-1]` where s is your desired string. This is using list slicing. You can look at documentation if you want to understand it further.

Comment: Yes I have done this but the brackets and apostrophes ['8:00'] still remain